# Ionic Angular HTTP POST request to PHP

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a basic POST request from my ionic angular app using the HttpClient from Angular. From that POST, I need to pass the payload to PHP file for me to manipulate another function in the PHP.

I can seem to echo the whole data, but trying to get the single value gives an error.

Below is my code under home.ts

```
test() {
    let data = {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Wick"
    }

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');

    this.http.post(this.php_url, data, {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("Posted successfully")
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err.error);
    });
  }
```

In my index.php file, I have the code below.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    echo $json->firstname;
?>
```

I am able to echo $json, but not when trying to get the single value. How do I get the single value from the JSON data?

Comment: You need to _decode_ the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
 print_r($json['firstname']);
```

insted of

```
 echo $json->firstname;
```